# Bash: Why does printf not respect newline char?

Tags: bash

Why does this bash script (at bottom) not output the newline?  The result is:

```
filesonetwothree
```

instead of

```
files
one
two
three
```

Here's the script:

```
files=()
files+="one"
files+="two"
files+="three"

printf "\nfiles"
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    printf "$file\n"
done
```

NOTE: This is on a Mac running macOS Sierra

Comment: You're appending to *the first array element* in `files`, not appending new elements to the array.

Comment: If you want to add new elements, you need to use `files+=( "$one" )`, not `files+="$one"`

Comment: Also, keep your data out of your format strings -- that is to say, you should use `printf '%s\n' "$file"` (or `printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"` to print them all at once).

Comment: Here's where I reply "DOH!"  Thanks. :-)

Comment: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically points out these issues, and can also be installed locally on macOS with homebrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will make your issue very clear:

```
files=()
files+="one"
files+="two"
files+="three"
declare -p files
```

...emits as output:

```
declare -a files='([0]="onetwothree")'
```

...so, you were appending *to the first element of the array*, not adding new elements to the array's end.

---

To correctly append to an array, use the following instead:

```
files=()
files+=("one")
files+=("two")
files+=("three")
declare -p files
```

...which emits:

```
declare -a files='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

---

In either case, to print your array one-line-to-an-element, use a format string with a newline, and pass your array elements as subsequent arguments:

```
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```